# jquery find() and remove() with script tag not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which removes a tag successfully from a given string. But now the problem is that if I don't try to remove a script tag, the following fun() function automatically removes the script tag. Could anybody try to explain it to me ?

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
  function fun(x)
  {
    alert(x);

    var html = $(x.bold()); 
    html.find('p').remove();
    return html.html();

    //alert(html);

  } 
</script>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="alert(fun('<script>hello script</script><p>hello p</p><div>hello div</div>'))">
```

Comment: what is `$(x.bold())`?

Comment: it simply wraps the string with <b> tag which I found on the net... @user1671639

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FArbJ/1/ any error in the browser console

Comment: thanks @ArunPJohny but I copy-pasted the function and tried in my pc which failed :(. what does var html = $('<div />', {
         html: x
     }); means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you will work, the problem I guess is that your **`jQuery`** is not added properly.

```
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>  <!-- jQuery Lib is not added properly-->
```

Here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YkqFe/) which is working accordingly.

Comment: I have even tried the external source from google APIs, was in vain.. please any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fun(x)
{
  alert(x);

  var html = x.bold();       
  html=$(html);
  html.find('p').remove();
  return($(html).html());
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FArbJ/2/